# Quickly finding policy on Xxxxx

Tags: support, policy

I sometimes find myself searching for policy on something so that I can point a poster to the policy, or refer to it myself for guidance.  Usually this is the homework policy, but sometimes it's something else such the policy on questions related to experimental physics.   But I seem to re-invent the wheel of finding the policy each time I need it, and for me the search does not go smoothly.

Is there some kind of central location for policies?  Or can you provide advice on how to find these things quickly?  It always seems to take me many clicks and many pages to find what I want.

Comment: You mean the [help center](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help)?

Comment: Hmm, there's also searching meta for the `faq` tag (e.g. by using the search bar on this site with `[faq]`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments pointed out, the [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help) and the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag on meta are the canonical sources. There's also a lot of site-agnostic information in the [faq tag on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq), which is mostly just clarifications of the stuff in the help center, but I would still consider that to be part of our policy.

Anything that you don't find in one of those sources, you can ask here on meta or in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar), although it's worth doing a quick search of meta to see if you can find any prior discussion about it.